# keras installed but can't be loaded

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to using keras or tensorflow.

I first used `conda install keras` in Anaconda Prompt to install keras. Then I go to Jupyter Notebook to call the keras using `import keras` or `from keras.datasets import mnist`. The error message showed as: No module named 'tensorflow'.

I didn't know whether keras must have tensorflow installed, then it can be called. Then I used `conda install tensorflow` in Anaconda Prompt again. The result was like this:
[image]

Then I rerun those statement to call keras again in Jupyter Notebook. Now the error message was: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

I didn't know what to do next to solve this problem to use keras.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Keras requires backend framework like Tensorflow you need to install Tensorflow first and then install Keras which will solve the issue.

After this you can either import keras from **import tensorflow.keras** or directly **import Keras**